# New to Load testing and Gatlng - Hoping you can help - Load & StressTesting Scenario

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, gatling

I am very very new to the load and stress testing space.

I'm working on a vacation e-commerce platform and we updating a part of it where a person can purchase a holiday item.

Now I want basically check the following things:

- how quickly page loads
- the number of individual that can purchase an item before it crashes.

What other Load and stress testing scenarios can I perform?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Load Testing and Stress testing are very different scenarios.

**Load testing** is more likely the upper limit of your system and checked how the system will handle under a heavy load.

**Stress testing** is more on how system behaves under extreme heavy load and how it will recover in case there will be a failure. Or shall we say that this is done with unexpected traffic on your website or apps.

Based on what you have, you only have load testing.

For stress testing example, try adding a scenario where you will send a large number of  GET request in your system repeatedly to know when it will breaks, and what how it behaves.